# Having Some problem when adding element to Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am working with Priority Queue problem in this link
[Hackkerank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-priority-queue/problem)

My Student class was created follow by OOP patterns which have constructor with 3 attributes **(id, Name, cgpa)** and some Getter method

My Priorities

```
class Priorities{
        private List<Student> list_student = new ArrayList<>();

    class  CheckCondition implements Comparator<Student>{


        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            if(o1.getCGPA() < o2.getCGPA()){
                return 1;
            }else if(o1.getCGPA() > o2.getCGPA()){
                return -1;
            }else{
                if(o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) < 0) {
                    return 1;
                }else if(o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) > 0){
                    return -1;
                }else {
                    if(o1.getID() < o2.getID()){
                        return -1;
                    }else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    public List<Student> getStudents(List<String> events, int capacity){
        Queue<Student> stringQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(capacity, new CheckCondition());
        if(events.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("EMPTY");
        }
        for(String element: events){
            List<String> stringList = List.of(element.split(" "));
            if(stringList.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("ENTER")){
                Student new_student = new   Student(Integer.parseInt(stringList.get(3)), stringList.get(1), Double.parseDouble(stringList.get(2)));
                stringQueue.add(new_student);
            }if(stringList.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("SERVED") ){
                stringQueue.poll();
            }
        }
        stringQueue.stream().forEach(element -> list_student.add(element));

        return list_student;

    }
}
```

My Main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         List<String> events = new ArrayList<>();
         Integer capacity = sc.nextInt();
         sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            events.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
    
        Priorities priorities = new Priorities();
        List<Student> students = priorities.getStudents(events, capacity);
    
        for(Student element: students){
            System.out.println(element.getName());
        }
    
    }

}
```

So When I try with the test case in Hackerrank, My result instead of as expect, I change slightly in the end of the Queue

Expect result:

```
Dan
Ashley
**Shafaet
Maria**
```

Actual result:

```
Dan
Ashley
**Maria
Shafaet**
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why I can have this result as I try many times but it showed an abnormal case when program add the "Anik" student in the Queue which also change to position or 2 student "Shafaet" and "Maria".

Thank everyone so much

Comment: Your compare method seems dodgy.  Your fist comparison is for gpa, but you give no details about gpa.  Also what about when the objects are equal?

Comment: not only the problem mentioned in previous comment, the `PriorityQueue` only *guarantees* that the head is in correct order, [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): "*The Iterator provided in method iterator() and the Spliterator provided in method spliterator() are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.*"

Comment: As you haven't shown the GPA for the students it's impossible to say whether they are in the expected order or not.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for all your comments, sorry about not providing the detail of gpa, it just an attribute of student which is double primitive type and no more complex

Comment: @user16320675 thanks for your information about the PriorityQueue, so what should I do when I want to guarantee of these another element in the Queue

Comment: But without knowing what GPA is associated with each of the students in your list, it's hard to say what order they should be in.

Comment: @HungNguyen I explained how to fix your code to allow it to pass in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names should be sorted in ascending order, so you should return `-1` when `o1`'s name comes before `o2` lexicographically.

```java
if (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) < 0) {
    return -1;
} else if (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) > 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

Also, you should return `0` when the ids are equal.

Another major issue is that the `stream` method for `PriorityQueue` does not guarantee order. You could `poll` all of the elements and add to the `List` instead.

```java
while (!stringQueue.isEmpty())
    list_student.add(stringQueue.poll());
```

Note that the `Comparator` can be written a lot more simply using the `Comparator.comparing` methods:

```java
Queue<Student> stringQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(capacity, 
        Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getCGPA).reversed()
            .thenComparing(Student::getName)
            .thenComparing(Student::getID));
```